# Intersection of two arrays using common key value for comparison

Tags: php, arrays

I want to perform an intersection of two arrays that have different structures, but both have one key common (`fid`). I want a new (filtered second) array after intersection with first array. below is my code and two arrays :

first array:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 3
            )  
    )
```

Second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 9
            [functionality] => testing
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 1
            [functionality] => add functionality
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 2
            [functionality] => view functionality category
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 3
            [functionality] => view functionality
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 4
            [functionality] => edit functionality
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )
)
```

I want this Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 1
            [functionality] => add functionality
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 3
            [functionality] => view functionality
            [funcat_id] => 1
            [name] => functionality
        )
)
```

I tried this code but I'm not getting the right answer:

```
$result=array_intersect($array1,$array2);
//Or this also
$result=recursive_array_intersect_key($array1,$array2);
```

Please let me know, if any one can do this ?

Comment: I dont think there is any function available for this in PHP. You will have to implement your own filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array2 as $val)
{
    $i=0;
    foreach($array1 as $val1)
    {
        if($val['fid']==$val1['fid'])
        {
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if($i!=0)
    {
        $a[]=$val;
    }
}

print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if a function does exists to do this outright, but alternatively, you can just loop them instead:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array2 as $val2) {
    foreach ($array1 as $val1) {
        if($val2['fid'] == $val1['fid']) {
            $result[] = $val2;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/F8o0Wd)

Or if you're using PHP 5.5 or greater:

```
$val1 = array_column($array1, 'fid');
$result = array_filter($array2, function($val2) use($val1) {
    return in_array($val2['fid'], $val1);
});
```